# ModelsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["application/xlsx"] request.variant: []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, export-to-csv, xlsx

Hope you're doing well.
I followed exactly [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/generate-excel-spreadsheets-rails-axlsx-gem/) Manual to create a new application and try exporting excel file using **axlsx_rails** Gem. This manual seems just fine and complete but when I click on line_to tag this error pops up

```
ProductsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"] request.variant: []
```

and this:

```
raise ActionController::UnknownFormat, message
```

I guess this error relates to my parameters or something like that.
I'm using **Rails 5**
Have any idea ?
Thanks a million :)

**Edit:**
this is my controller:

```
def index
     @products = Product.order('created_at DESC')

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xlsx {
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="all_products.xlsx"'
      }
     end
  end
```

view index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Download as .xlsx', products_path(format: :xlsx) %>
```

view  index.xlsx.axlsx

```
  wb = xlsx_package.workbook
    wb.add_worksheet(name: "Products") do |sheet|
      @products.each do |product|
        sheet.add_row [product.title, product.price]
      end
    end
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Comment: @JagjotSingh Sure Right now!

Comment: When you click the link, what URL is generated?

Comment: @JagjotSingh this /products.xlsx

Comment: I just tried the whole tutorial myself and it seems to run perfectly. I have only suggestion that did you restart your server after installing `axlsx_rails` gem?

Comment: @JagjotSingh Yes many times! What about the initializer mime? did you add it ? If you succeed it's better to do the whole thing once again. Thank you for putting you time on this.

Comment: No, never needed to put any mime anywhere. I just added the gem, controller and the `index.xlxs.axlxs` file. Ping if you are still having trouble with it. I'll upload my code to a repository so that you can test that as well.

Comment: @JagjotSingh Shockingly When I tried as a second time every thing worked out well! I barely know what was the problem! BTW thank you :)

Comment: Haha I can understand. Glad everything worked out well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution
**Controller**:

```
def export_to_excel
    @tests = Test.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xlsx {
          response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="official_letters.xlsx"'
            }
    end
end
```

this is **views/ ... export_to_excel.xlsx.axlsx**

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "tests") do |sheet|
  @tests.each do |test|
    sheet.add_row [test.title, test.price]
end
```